# How to set PowerShell Core window title programmatically?

Tags: powershell

I used to have this script in my PowerShell 6.x profile, that updated my window title to the name of the current Git repository:

```
function Set-Title([string] $title) {
  $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $title  
}

$gitDir = git rev-parse --show-toplevel
if ($gitDir) {
  $repoName = Split-Path $gitDir -Leaf
  Set-Title $repoName
}
```

However in pwsh this title only appears for a brief second, and then is reset to the name of current directory. How do I force mine?

Comment: that code works for me with ps7 and the default console. are you using the "new" windows terminal?

Comment: The Set-Title function works in WT as well. Yet, FYI, that title is only for that tab you are in not any other tab. There is no standalone title bar in WT, the title bar is the tab.

Comment: [Posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) sets the window title to the name of current git repo and branch.

Do you happen to have a PowerShell module installed that could be overriding what you set `$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle` to? When I have posh-git installed, it overrides what I set `$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle` to.